# How to bind View size to a parameter

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to bind a View width to a parameter like this

```
android:layout_width='@{String.valueOf((int)item.parameter)+"dp"}'
```

which can be something like

```
android:layout_width='@{"156dp"}'
```

Which results in

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.view.View.
```

So how do I bind the item parameter to the View width correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in Java code, the layout_width is an integer attribute that expects the value to be in pixels.  The unit suffixes that you supply in XML are used to convert the value in xml from dp to pixels prior to passing the value to layout_width.  I think the property you are binding to should be an **integer** property which supplies the value in pixels.  If item.parameter is an integer value that you want in dp units, you could do something like this for item.bindingParameter:

```
    Configuration cfg = getResources().getConfiguration();
    return item.parameter * cfg.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, now it makes sense.